# change of index on -infinite and +infinite summation

Tags: summation

I am simplifying the following equation.

$$ =\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}{ x_k \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}{h_{n-k}}}$$

If sum index for $n$ is changed to $r=n-k$, where $n = r+k$.

$$ =\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}x_k \sum_{r=-\infty-k}^{\infty-k}{h_r}$$

Question: $\Rightarrow$ is it valid to change the index of the second summation as follows:
$$\{-\infty-k \rightarrow -\infty\} \text{ and } \{\infty-k \rightarrow \infty\}$$

$$ = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}{ x_k \sum_{r=-\infty}^{\infty}{h_r}}$$

Comment: Can you clarify the order of operations? From the way that you've written it, I'm guessing that you are taking the product of two series. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct it is a product of two series.